# Не компилируется код PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

После того как я создаю exe файл через pyinstaller с пакетом PyQt5, программу все время крашит при запуске. С другими файлами все нормально. В PATH ничего кроме Python не стоит

Скачать файлы которые я пытался превратить в EXE: https://yadi.sk/d/Gb4lnsqYsvO3Qg

Варны из логов PyInstaller:

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional module. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level), getpass (optional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed)
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading (optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named org - imported by copy (optional), C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneMacro.py (top-level)
missing module named 'Xlib.XK' - imported by pyautogui._pyautogui_x11 (top-level)
missing module named 'Xlib.ext' - imported by pyautogui._pyautogui_x11 (top-level)
missing module named Xlib - imported by mouseinfo (conditional), pyautogui._pyautogui_x11 (top-level)
missing module named 'Xlib.display' - imported by pyautogui._pyautogui_x11 (top-level)
missing module named AppKit - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional), mouseinfo (conditional), pyautogui._pyautogui_osx (top-level)
missing module named Quartz - imported by mouseinfo (conditional, optional), pyautogui._pyautogui_osx (optional)
missing module named Tkinter - imported by pymsgbox (conditional, optional), mouseinfo (conditional, optional), PIL.ImageTk (conditional)
missing module named olefile - imported by PIL.MicImagePlugin (top-level), PIL.FpxImagePlugin (top-level)
missing module named UserDict - imported by PIL.PdfParser (optional)
missing module named 'PySide.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'PyQt4.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'PySide2.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named PySide2 - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy - imported by PIL.ImageFilter (optional), pyscreeze (optional)
missing module named pathlib2 - imported by PIL.Image (optional)
missing module named cffi - imported by PIL.Image (optional), PIL.PyAccess (top-level), PIL.ImageTk (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by PIL.Image (optional)
missing module named PIL._imagingagg - imported by PIL (delayed, conditional, optional), PIL.ImageDraw (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named PyQt4 - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named Foundation - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'PyQt4.QtGui' - imported by pyperclip (delayed, optional)
missing module named qtpy - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named gtk - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named cv2 - imported by pyscreeze (optional)
missing module named port_v2 - imported by PyQt5.uic.properties (conditional)
missing module named StringIO - imported by PyQt5.uic.port_v2.string_io (optional)
missing module named cStringIO - imported by PyQt5.uic.port_v2.string_io (optional)
missing module named copy_reg - imported by cStringIO (top-level)
```

Ошибка при запуске exe файла:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "InsaneMacro.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py", line 33, in find_qt
ImportError: unable to find Qt5Core.dll on PATH
[11920] Failed to execute script InsaneMacro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Насколько мне известно, pyinstaller включает в сборку только те модули, которые импортируются из главного файла. То есть, если Вы сделали `pyinstaller some_script.py`, а при этом в `some_script.py` есть импорт **другого модуля, в котором тоже что-то импортируется**, то импорты этого другого модуля не будут включены в сборку! Имейте это в виду.
2. Текст ошибки говорит о том, что Ваша программа не может найти файл `Qt5Core.dll`. Найдите его вручную и положите в тот же каталог, где лежит результирующий `.exe`.
3. Вы используете неправильный термин в своём вопросе. В Вашем случае код не *не компилируется*, а скорее *не исполняется* или некорректно собирается. Python – интерпретируемый язык.

P.S. Я надеюсь, Вы установили все используемые приложением модули для Python, прежде чем использовать pyinstaller для сборки приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Я столкнулся с той же проблемой.
Проблема заключается в файле `__init__.py`, который у меня располагался в папке `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5` 
Я не смогу объяснить суть, ведь я внёс правки в него и не могу увидеть вариант 'до', но я смогу предложить решение.
Первый вариант, это изменить код самого файла:

```
def find_qt():
    import os
    path = os.environ['PATH']
    dll_dir = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin'
    if os.path.isfile(dll_dir + '\\Qt5Core.dll'):
        path = dll_dir + ';' + path
        os.environ['PATH'] = path
    else:
        for dll_dir in path.split(';'):
            if os.path.isfile(dll_dir + '\\Qt5Core.dll'):
                break
        else:
            raise ImportError("unable to find Qt5Core.dll on PATH")

    try:
        os.add_dll_directory(dll_dir)
    except AttributeError:
        pass


find_qt()
del find_qt
```

Вместо `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32` вставьте путь к своей папке с python (не забыв продублировать слэши), если отличается версия или она установлена только для одного пользователя и находится в appdata.

А второй вариант, это при каждом запуске pyinstaller добавлять в конец команды флаг `--paths "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin"`, изменив только путь к папке с python